# How can I set a compiler error or at least a warning for multi-character literals?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012, compiler-construction, compiler-warnings

If I have

```
int i = 'ABCD'
```

how can I set a compiler warning or error?  I am using visual studio 11's compiler for c++.  A .net project gives a compiler error by default as so: `Too many characters in character literal`.

Comment: I don't know about vendor-specific warnings, but this is legal in both C and C++ according to the spec (they are called *multicharacter literals* and have type `int`). It's not legal in .NET, hence that error.

Comment: are you setting the correct tag? I did a google and I only saw questions about the error on C#

Comment: I know it's legal  but it can be pretty dangerous if accidentally passed to an overloaded method `func(int i), func(char c)`.  Just wanted to see if there was at least a way to say, "hey are you sure you wanna do this"

Comment: At the risk of someone coming along and telling me how great multi-character literals are, I think it's pretty stupid that it's allowed

Comment: The standard says it's implementation-defined. But I don't think there is a way to display a warning for this in VS, and I don't think it would help much; it seems like a pretty arbitrary thing to warn about.

Comment: I would guess that one big motivation for not showing a warning is because the Windows SDK also contains plenty of multi-char literals.

Comment: From http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf, 2.14.3.1 on page 25

Comment: @Jon: They're a language feature, not a .NET feature. They're legal in C and C++, but it's usually a bad idea to use them -- thus the desire for a warning. (gcc warns about them by default.)

Comment: If you can't coax your compiler to warn about them, you should still be able to search your source files. If you have something like `grep`, searching for `'...*'` is likely to produce some false positives (for things like `'\n'`, or even for two ordinary character constants on the same line), but it should find all multi-character literals.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I don't think I said anything different :-)

Comment: @Jon: As I recall, you can use C++ with .NET. I guess the OP was referring to an error message from a C# compiler.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes, that's a C# error. You are referring to C++/CLI, where to be frank I have no idea what would happen if you tried this.

Comment: @Pittfall: They are indeed pretty handy for code that works on [FOURCC values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FourCC).  Would be nice if there was a different syntax required, I agree, but unless you're going to make your own language, you're stuck with someone else's rules.

Answer (score -1):

Does this work?

```
-Wno-multichar
```

Maybe for Visual C++:

```
/W4XXXX
```

where 'XXXX' is the error number for the warning (if you can find it).  This would set the sensitivity really high for that warning so hopefully it will let you know about it.

Comment: Why would it? That's a gcc option.

Comment: yes that is a gcc option and visual studio uses CL for c++.